# Feynman parametrisation integration shift

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I would like to derive a certain form of Feynman parameterization from a more conventional sort.

For example in the standard case for  $a$ and $b$  propagators:

$\dfrac{1}{ab}=\int_{0} ^1 \dfrac{dx}{[(a-b)x+b]^2}$

How do I derive

$\dfrac{2}{(a.b)(a.c)}=\int_{-1}^1 \dfrac{dx}{[\frac{1}{2}a((b+c)+x(b-c))]^2}$

from the first equation above?

Comment: Linearly transform $x$ in each equation so both integrals are of the form $\int_A^B\frac{du}{u^2}$. Then double-check your statement of the desired result.

Comment: If I do this the first integral is
$\int_{b}^a \frac{du}{u^2(a-b)}$. 
Then I  take $a=1$ and $b=-1$ I get
$\int_{-1}^1 \frac{du}{2u^2}$.?

Comment: Maybe I should have been clearer: rewrite both the assumed result & the desired one in the form $\int_A^B\frac{du}{u^2}=C$.

Comment: OK in that case the second integral is:
$\int_{ac}^{ab} \frac{2du}{a(b-c)u^2}$ but it is still not clear to me they are equivalent.

Comment: In the second integral I can take $a=1$ and I get $\int_{c}^{b} \frac{2du}{(b-c)u^2}$ and then I take $c=-1$ and $b=1$ to find $\int_{-1}^{1} \frac{du}{u^2}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The desired result is off by a factor of $2$. For example, if $b=c$ the integral is $\int_{-1}^1\frac{dx}{[ab]^2}=\frac{2}{a^2b^2}$. Presumably, the $\frac12$ in the denominator was meant to be outside the square.

With that said, from $\int_b^a\frac{du}{u^2}=\frac{a-b}{ab}$ we want to prove $\int_{ac}^{ab}\frac{du}{u^2}=\frac{b-c}{abc}$. This is just a matter of replacing $a,\,b$ in the original equation with $ab,\,ac$.

Comment: Apologises, there was a missing factor of 2 but it was on the LHS of the second equation. Thanks for your help, this has clarified the issue for me.